# List of keys or separate model?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building an app with users and their activities. Now I'm thinking of the best way of setting up the datastore models. Which one is fastest/preferred, and why?

A

```
class User(db.Model):
    activities = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    ...
class Activity(db.Model):
    ...

activities = db.get(user.activities)
```

or

B

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
class Activity(db.Model):
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=User)
    ...

activities = Activity.filter('owner =', user)
```

Comment: Although the answers are good, it's worth noting that you haven't really provided enough information. What matters about which solution is better is how you are going to use the data. What sort of queries will you do? How many activities will each user have? etc.

Comment: New activities will be created as users interact, e.g. follow each others or recommend things. In such case, an outgoing activity will be stored for the user committing the activity and an icoming activity will be stored for receiving users if there are any. A users activities will be fetched when visiting that users profile page or when that user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

If a given activity can only have a single owner, definitely use a `ReferenceProperty`.

- It's what `ReferenceProperty`s are designed for
- It'll automatically set up back-references for you, which can be handy since it gives you a bi-directional link (unlike the `ListProperty` which is a uni-directional link)
- It enforces that the thing being linked to is the proper type/class
- It enforces that only a single user is linked to a given activity
- It lets you automatically fetch the linked objects without having to write an explicit query, if you so desire

Comment: Even if I don't have to look up the owner from an activity?

Comment: Yes, even if you don't. See all the other bullet points. (That said, I think you may find down the road that you want to be able to look up the owner from an activity at some point - it's better to have the capability available than not.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the difference is going to be marginal and will likely depend more on your application than some concrete difference in read/write times based on your models.

I would say use the first option if you're going to use info from every activity a user has done each time you fetch a user.  In other words, if almost everything a user does on your application coincides with a large subset of their activities, then it makes sense to always have the activities available.

Use option B if you don't need the activities all of the time.  This will result in a separate request on the data store whenever you need to use the activity, but it will also make the requests smaller.  Making an extra request likely adds more overhead than making bigger requests.

All of that being said, I would be surprised if you had a noticeable difference between these two approaches.  The area where you're going to get much more noticeable performance improvements is by using memcache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the performance difference, I suspect it'll be similar.  When it comes to perf, things are hard to control with the GAE datastore.  If all your queries happen to hit the same tablet (bigtable server), that could limit your perf more than the query itself.

The big difference is that A would be cheaper than B.  Since you have a list of activities you want, you don't need to write an index for every activity object you write.  If activities are written a lot, your savings add up.

Since you have the activity key, you also have the ability to do a highly-consistent get() rather than an eventually consistent filter()

On the flip side, you won't be able to do backwards references, like look up an owner given an activity.  Your ListProperty can also cause you to hit your maximum entity size - there will eventually be a hard limit on the number of activities per user.  If you went with B, you can have a huge number of activities per user.

Edit: I forgot, you *can* have backwards reference if you index your ListProperty, but then that way, writing your User object would get expensive, and the limit on the number of indexed properties would limit the size of your list.  So even though it's possible, B is still preferable if you need backwards references.

Answer (score 0):

A will be a good deal faster because it is working purely with keys.  Looking up objects with just keys goes straight to the data node in BigTable, whereas B requires a lookup on the indices first which is slower (and costs will go up with the number of Activity entities).

If you never need to test for ownership, you can modify A to not index the key list. This is definitely the cheapest and most efficient route. However, as I understand it, if you later need to index them app engine cannot retroactively update indices on the key list. So only disable the index if you're certain you'll never need it.

Answer (score 0):

How about C: setting Activity's parent to user key? So that you can fetch user's activities with a Activity.query(ancestor=user.key).

That way you don't need additional keys/properties + good way to group your entities for HR datastore.